# Evaluating a 2d integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to calculate this integral

\begin{align*}
I(s_1,s_2,s_{12},m) =
\int_{0}^{1} {\rm d}x \int_{0}^{1-x}
{\rm d}y \Big( 
x y 
\Big[
y(1-y)s_1 + x(1-x)s_2 + 2 xy s_{12} -m^2
\Big]^{-1}
\Big),
\end{align*}
where $s_{1}, s_{2}, s_{12}$ and $m$ are constant real values.

To evaluate this integral, I've used

```
$Assumptions = Element[{s1, s2, s12, m}, Reals] &&  s1 >= 0 && s2 >= 0 && m >= 0; 

FullSimplify[
  Integrate[Integrate[
    x*y/(y*(1 - y)*s1 + x*(1 - x)*s2 + 2*x*y* s12 - m^2), {y, 0, 1 - x}], {x, 0, 1}]] // Timing
```

This evaluation is very slow, and I wasn't able to get the final result. Does anyone have a suggestion to speed up the calculation?

Comment: I managed to break up the integral and compute one integration (w.r.t. x), but then I tried to put that result into a $y$ integral and it never terminated.  It might just be that this integral has no closed-form solution or is beyond *Mathematica*'s power.

Comment: I think we first should integrate over y as its limits depend on x. The analytical form of these types of integrals is reported in some papers but I have the impression that they have some typos and that is why I am trying to integrate them.

Comment: In general case, this is an improper double integral as the result of `s1 = 1; s2 = 2; s12 = 3; 
  m = 1; Reduce[
    y*(1 - y)*s1 + x*(1 - x)*
            s2 + 2*x*y*s12 - 
          m^2 == 0 && x >= 0 && 
      x <= 1 && y >= 0 && 
      y <= 1 - x, {x, y}]`, i.e. `1/6 (3 - Sqrt[5]) <= x <= 1/6 (3 + Sqrt[5]) && 
 y == 1/2 (1 + 6 x) - 1/2 Sqrt[-3 + 20 x + 28 x^2]` shows. Its  convergence is unclear to me..

Comment: There is condition that $s_{12}=s_1 s_2$. The solutions that are suggested in the papers contain dilogarithm and logarithm functions

Comment: This does not matter:`s1 = 1; s2 = 2; s12 = s1*s2; m = 1; Reduce[
 y*(1 - y)*s1 + x*(1 - x)*s2 + 2*x*y*s12 - m^2 == 0 && x >= 0 && 
  x <= 1 && y >= 0 && y <= 1 - x, {x, y}]` results in `1/14 (7 - Sqrt[21]) <= x <= 1/14 (7 + Sqrt[21]) && 
 y == 1/2 (1 + 4 x) - 1/2 Sqrt[-3 + 16 x + 8 x^2]`. I have strong doubts about the convergence of the improper double integral under consideration.

Comment: @Shasa Can you give a link to the paper mentioned above?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Here is one of those papers: https://inspirehep.net/files/44924f9a3b9a71aca8ce019a36428efc Eq.(2.8) is the generic form of integral and the final results are given in Eqs. (2.13-2.15) based on relations given in Eqs. (2.6, 2.7).

Comment: @Shasa But they obtained explicit form for massless case only, that means $m=0$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev the massive results are presented in Eqs. (3.3-3.5).

Comment: @Shasa It is not clear how Eqs. (3.3-3.5) connected with integral discussed. But anyway even in massless case  Mathematica 12.2 has no answer.